# Snowflake SQL, how to lookahead until a certain occurrence of a value

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below is a sample of the text that I am working with.

```
--- 
info1:
*  val: "A"
---
Type:
*  answers:
*  - !<string>
*    val: "B"
*  - !<string>
*    val: "C"
--- 
info2:
*  val: "D"
---
```

And I am trying to select the following text:

```
Type:
*  answers:
*  - !<string>
*    val: "B"
*  - !<string>
*    val: "C"
```

I was trying to use a look ahead, but haven't had much success. 
`REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'Type:(.*---)')`
Here I am trying to look up until the next occurrence of '---', but I think I misunderstanding how it works.

Comment: Where is `lossType:`  or any `/` character in the sample text ?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been corrected. It has been fixed now.

Comment: Not sure what regex engine they use. These are a few ways it can be done.: `Type:[\S\s]*?(?:---|$)` or `Type:[\S\s]*?(?=---|$)` or `(?s)Type:.*?(?=---|$)`

Comment: those three patterns all fail with `Invalid regular expression: '(?s)Type:.*?(?=---|$)', no argument for repetition operator: ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regexp lookahead to get the string you want, it's just eg.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '(^Type:\\s+(^[*].*$\\s+)*)^---', 1, 1, 'm', 1)
```

If you need regexps with lookahead, etc, use JavaScript RegExps via a function wrapper, eg.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RegExp_Match("STRING" VARCHAR, "REGEXP" VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARIANT LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT STRICT IMMUTABLE AS
'return STRING.match(REGEXP);';
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RegExp_Match("STRING" VARCHAR, "RX" VARCHAR, "FLAGS" VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARIANT LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT STRICT IMMUTABLE AS
'return STRING.match(new RegExp(RX, FLAGS));';

SELECT RegExp_Match('<aA>', '(?<=<)(.)\\1(?=>)', 'i');
-- RegExp with lookback, back reference and lookahead ignoring case
=> [ "aA", "a" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

[REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html) is rather limited in snowflake, in native SQL, so when you tell is to match multiple lines and match newlines via `REGEXP_SUBSTR(t, '(Type:.*)---',1,1,'mes',1)` the regexp is greddy thus:

```
SELECT '--- 
info1:
*  val: "A"
---
Type:
*  answers:
*  - !<string>
*    val: "B"
*  - !<string>
*    val: "C"
--- 
info2:
*  val: "D"
---' as t
,REGEXP_SUBSTR(t, '(Type:.*)',1,1,'mes',1) as r1 
,REGEXP_SUBSTR(t, '(Type:.*)---',1,1,'mes',1) as r2;
```

gives you too much data:

```
Type:
*  answers:
*  - !<string>
*    val: "B"
*  - !<string>
*    val: "C"
--- 
info2:
*  val: "D"
```

So one idea is if `---` is always a section marker, is to string split on that first and then regex

```
WITH input as (
select '--- 
info1:
*  val: "A"
---
Type:
*  answers:
*  - !<string>
*    val: "B"
*  - !<string>
*    val: "C"
--- 
info2:
*  val: "D"
---' as t
)
select t, c.value::string as part, REGEXP_SUBSTR(part, 'Type:.*',1,1,'mes') as r1 
from input,
     lateral flatten(input=>split(t, '---')) c;
```

gives

```
T   PART    R1
---   info1:  *  val: "A"  ---  Type:  *  answers:  *  - !<string>  *    val: "B"  *  - !<string>  *    val: "C"  ---   info2:  *  val: "D"  ---        
---   info1:  *  val: "A"  ---  Type:  *  answers:  *  - !<string>  *    val: "B"  *  - !<string>  *    val: "C"  ---   info2:  *  val: "D"  ---       info1:  *  val: "A"      
---   info1:  *  val: "A"  ---  Type:  *  answers:  *  - !<string>  *    val: "B"  *  - !<string>  *    val: "C"  ---   info2:  *  val: "D"  ---      Type:  *  answers:  *  - !<string>  *    val: "B"  *  - !<string>  *    val: "C"      Type:  *  answers:  *  - !<string>  *    val: "B"  *  - !<string>  *    val: "C"  
---   info1:  *  val: "A"  ---  Type:  *  answers:  *  - !<string>  *    val: "B"  *  - !<string>  *    val: "C"  ---   info2:  *  val: "D"  ---       info2:  *  val: "D"      
---   info1:  *  val: "A"  ---  Type:  *  answers:  *  - !<string>  *    val: "B"  *  - !<string>  *    val: "C"  ---   info2:  *  val: "D"  ---
```

from which you should be able to progress.

Also if you need really complex regexp, you can make a javascript-UDF and use the javascript regexp engine..

Comment: `those three patterns all fail with Invalid regular expression:`  What did you get when you tried this `Type:[\S\s]*?(?:---|$)` which is one of the three ? After all, just trying to over come greediness and add a dot-all type behavior . No need to go through split gyrations. There does seem to be <regex_parameters> supported there so, a simple `Type:.*?(?:---|$)` will work with the s modifier parameter `s: the ‘.’ wildcard also matches newline.

Comment: all three had the same error that `no argument for repetition operator: ?`, but to humour you, `Invalid regular expression: 'Type:[Ss]*?(?:---|$)', no argument for repetition operator: ?` and `Invalid regular expression: 'Type:.*?(?:---|$)', no argument for repetition operator: ?` it's almost like the `(?` repetition operator is not supported.

Comment: but as I said, snowflake SQL regex is very simple, if  you need more complex regex, use a js-udf like noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188198/snowflake-sql-regex-extracting-multiple-vals/59200886#59200886

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake does not support look-aheads or look-behinds, but it does support group extraction (and nested group extraction).  These can be used within REGEXP_REPLACE or REGEXP_SUBSTR.  In this case, I prefer REGEXP_SUBSTR as you are looking to extract from, as opposed to replace within.  In my example below you will see both.

You have 3 dashes (-) that work as your delimiter, the issue becomes that you have a dash within your data.  I would advise replacing the delimiter with something that will NOT exist within your data, I chose a tilde (~).

The code sample below will work.

**Notes:**

- Column C2 operates on the KEEPS_LEADING_SPACE column which does not remove the leading space. In this case, the leading space is the first capture group.
- Column C3 operates on the actual data column but assumes that the leading space is one or more of a space, carriage return, newline, or vertical space.

**Capture Groups:**

1. (~([^~]+))? - captures something starts with a tilde (~) zero or more times, and within it
2. ([^~]+) - captures anything that is not a tilde (~) one or more times

```
USE ROLE SYSADMIN;
USE WAREHOUSE PUBLIC_WH;
USE UTIL_DB.PUBLIC;

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE REGEXP_TEST
AS
SELECT $1::VARIANT AS C1
FROM VALUES 
($$ 
--- 
info1:
*  val: "A"
---
Type:
*  answers:
*  - !<string>
*    val: "B"
*  - !<string>
*    val: "C"
--- 
info2:
*  val: "D"
---
$$);


SELECT C1
    ,REPLACE(C1,'---','~') AS KEEPS_LEADING_SPACE
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(KEEPS_LEADING_SPACE,'(~([^~]+))?',1,4,'is') AS C2
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(C1,'[\s\r\n\v]?-{3}','~'),'(~([^~]+))?',1,3,'is') AS C3
FROM REGEXP_TEST
;
```

Regex in Snowflake does support negatives but I tend to find them hard to work with if you are looking for more than one character, but in this case we have one character to negate the tilde [^~].