# Extracting multiple substrings from a single string using regular expressions in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently, I am working on extracting `substring` from a single string using `regular expressions` in `Snowflake`. This is what I have as of now.

e.g. `String = 'These are the Id's which I have WPD4567, WPD36785 also this is another id WPD111234 '`

I want to extract all the `substrings` starting with `WPD` i.e. `WPD4567` `WPD36785` `WPD111234`.

I want to have these substrings in the same column or different columns.

**This is what I have tried as of now:**

```
select 
   REGEXP_SUBSTR('These are the Id's which I have WPD4567, WPD36785 also this is another id WPD111234 ','(WPD)(.*)\\d*')
```

**Actual Output :** `WPD111234`

**Expected Output :** `WPD4567` `WPD36785` `WPD111234`

Comment: have you looked at a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188198/snowflake-sql-regex-extracting-multiple-vals the javascript UDF version makes a lot of sense if you are wanting all values in a single row? It is not clear what you "three values in a row" represents in a SQL row,column context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the idea of solving this with a JS UDF, but this is a solution with pure SQL, using `split_to_table()`:

```sql
with data as (
    select $1 id, $2 val, $3 s
    from values(
        1, 'x', $$These are the Id's which I have WPD4567, WPD36785 also this is another id WPD111234$$
    ),(
        2, 'y', $$WPD10101 These are the Id's which I have WPD4567, WPD36785 also this is another id WPD111234$$
    )
)

select any_value(data.id) id, any_value(data.val) val 
    , listagg('WPD' || regexp_substr(value, '[\\d]*'), ' ') wpds
from data, table(split_to_table(s, 'WPD'))
where index>1
group by seq
```

[image]